# Terminating app due to uncaught exception

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a code that kill's my app with this exception "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage initWithImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd815930'"

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        [self addImageWithName:@"image10.jpg" atPosition:0];

        for (int i=1; i< 11; i++) {
            [self addImageWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%i.jpg",i] atPosition:i];
        }

        [self addImageWithName:@"image1.jpg" atPosition:11];

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1920, 416);
        [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 416) animated:NO];
    }
    -(void)addImageWithName:(NSString *)imageString atPosition:(int)position{

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageString];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImage alloc] initWithImage:image];

        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(position*320, 0, 320, 416);
        [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release];

    }
```

and I dont know where my mistake is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImage alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

Replace this with this

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImage alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

should be

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

Answer (score 1):

UIImageView *imageView = [[**UIImageView** alloc] initWithImage:image];